# Why i cant install GCC-3.2-1?

Tags: gcc, redhat, libstdc++

Am beginner in Red Hat and I want to install gcc-3.2-1.i386.rpm and the following error are displayed.

Command line :

```
 #rpm --install gcc3.2-1.i386
```

error: required dependencies:
libstdc ++ is deprecated by gcc-2: 3.2-1.i386

Comment: I see no connection to Informix.  GCC 3.x is archaic. Why would you want to install it?

Comment: For the older compiler GCC for adapte with the version of RedHat

Answer (score 0):

Agree. Very old. What version of RHEL are you using?

Comment: RHEL :8.2
Informix dynamic server: 14.10 FC4W1
4Gl : 7.32.UC2

Answer (score 0):

It seems this version of gcc is so old that can be found in repos only for RedHat 7.x. It is very old. For current Red Hat enterprice linux version (8) actual version of gcc is 8.2.1 for example. (See [rpm.pbone.net link](http://rpm.pbone.net/results_limit_2_srodzaj_1_dl_40_dist%5B%5D_113_field%5B%5D_1_field%5B%5D_2_search_gcc.html))